# Voice to Text transfer in apex Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, text

I have a requirement to convert voice to text for searching purpose.
I am trying to have this below page in an iframe inside Visualforce page. It is working. Problem is that I need to modify the headers shown here.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

I am unable to do that right now. Can someone please help me here? Can it be possible using javascript or any other ready made plugin where I can modify the headers too?

Thanks.

Comment: What headers do you need to modify? We're missing a bit of information here.

Comment: By "headers" do you mean the "Web Speech API Demonstration" text?

Comment: Yes. Exactly! Please help me use this with customizing the header "Web Speech API Demonstration" here.

Comment: @gNerb Please help me know if I can do this.